# How to install webpack-cli?

Tags: webpack

I have installed webpack 4.5.0.

When I try to run webpack, it complains that it wants webpack-cli.

If I run `npm install webpack-cli` I get the following error:

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli
Would you like to install webpack-cli? (That will run npm install -D webpack-cli) (yes/NO)yes
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.14 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ webpack-cli@2.0.14
updated 1 package in 14.175s
{ Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at runCommand.then.result (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:62:14)
    at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Anybody has seen this and fixed it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the folder `node_modules` and reinstalling `webpack-cli` again?

Comment: arggh just came here to say that's what solved it for me

Comment: Make it an answer then :)

Comment: I've forgotten what was the solution to the problem already, but it might be useful for others.

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me by installing below modules:

npm i -g webpack-cli

npm install --save-dev webpack

npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because while `webpack-cli` might be installed globally, it is not installed in your current project, and somehow the project isn't capable of using the globally-installed version.

I fixed this by running `npm install webpack-cli` in the relevant project directory.